# How to make an iframe zoom with the page

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have an iframe with some content.
When i zoom out the content in the iframe does not zoom with the page, it stays the same size therefor causing scroll bars to appear, giving away the fact that its an iframe. 
Is there a way to make the iframe zoom with the page?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have not given details on your lines of code or the browser you are working on, but ,
here's what you can try to achieve your goal.

```
<style>
    #frameScale { width: 1390px; height: 2940px; padding: 0; position:relative; left:-90px; top:0px; overflow: hidden; }
    #frame { width: 1390px; height: 2940px; position:relative; left:-55px; top:0px; }
    #frame { -ms-zoom: 0.7; -moz-transform: scale(0.7); -moz-transform-origin: 0px 0; -o-transform: scale(0.7); -o-transform-origin: 0 0; -webkit-transform: scale(0.7); -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0; }
</style>
<div id="frameScale ">
    <iframe id="frame" src="Give Some URL Source Here"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: This is really awesome!